# Change logging level for urllib3 in boto3

Tags: logging, boto3

`boto3` seems to use its own copy of `urrlib3`. It also produces a whole lot of dropped connections. As a result, using the `info` level of `logging` is pretty much useless when working with `boto3` with a large number of connections.

Normally, these annoying messages could be suppressed as in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28867840/why-do-i-constantly-see-resetting-dropped-connection-when-uploading-data-to-my). Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to work for `boto3`. Is there a workaround?