# How to open a session and run each request on its own thread?

Tags: python, multithreading, python-requests, python-multithreading

I am trying to connect to a server and download all the attachments from said server. I have these 2 functions. download_File() simply downloads the file from the server.
downloadFiles()
1. connects to the server and gets file links
2. makes a dictionary of the names and links
3. calls download_File() on each file and runs on its own thread

for the test I am running, I have around 45 attachments but in reality it can be much more

```
def download_File(name, url):
    res = r.get(url,headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json' , 'Authorization':f"Bearer {token}"})
    with open(name, "wb") as f:
        f.write(res.content)    


def downloadFiles(link, outputPath):
    attachments = r.get(f"https://server.com/server/rest/api/content/{page_id}/child/attachment",headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json' , 'Authorization':f"Bearer {token}"})
    attachments = json.loads(attachments.text)
    linksDict={}
    for picture in attachments["results"]:
        linksDict[picture['title']] = "https://server/server"+ picture['_links']["download"]
    threads= []
    for title in linksDict:
        t=threading.Thread(target=download_File, args=[os.path.join(outputPath,title), linksDict[title]])
        t.start()
        threads.append(t)
```

I would like to optimize this process. The problem I have is when I run download_File() in parallel the program runs slower than when I run them back to back in a basic loop.

Also how can I set up a session to reduce the time it takes to connect and authenticate with the server. How can I set up 1 session for 45+ threads.

Comment: Unfortunately, requests.Session objects are not thread-safe. Also, with 45+ concurrent threads, you may be suffering from contention at the network layer. Sometimes less is more. Try using a thread pool and vary its size

Comment: @CtrlZ how can i use a thread pool in this situation?

Comment: On a single HTTP (HTTP/1.1) connection it's impossible to have multiple pending downloads. That's not an immediate problem for you, because by default `requests.get` opens a new HTTP connection for each call. If you want to reuse HTTP connections for subsequent downloads, use `requests.Session` (like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25239650/python-requests-speed-up-using-keep-alive), and add appropriate locking so that a session (HTTP connection) is used only by 1 thread at a time.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using a ThreadPoolExecutor. The default number of workers will be determined in accordance with your hardware setup and is usually a good choice.

Here's your code but restructured:

```
import requests
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
from pathlib import Path

# assign these 3 variables appropriately
page_id = 100
token = "myToken"
outputPath = Path("/tmp")

headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': f"Bearer {token}"
}
a_url = "https://server.com/confluence/rest/api/content/{page_id}/child/attachment"

def getLinks():
    with requests.get(a_url, headers=headers) as response:
        response.raise_for_status()
        for picture in response.json()["results"]:
            #                       
            yield picture["title"], f"https://server.com/confluence{picture['_links']["download"]}"
            #                       ^ THIS LOOK DUBIOUS  Should there be a forward slash after confluence ^


def process(t):
    title, url = t
    with requests.get(url, headers=headers) as response:
        response.raise_for_status()
        with open(outputPath / title, "wb") as data:
            data.write(response.content)

def main():
    with ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
        executor.map(process, getLinks())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Obviously this is untested but hopefully you get the idea

Comment: @ahmad The URLs in the answer are taken from your original question

Comment: @ahmad What's more relevant (given that the hostname you posted isn't publicly available) is whether this technique works for you

Comment: yes it worked, I made some changes based on what you recommended and it worked fine